# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 disable OIDC / disable requirement user-info

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I configured a custom OAuth2 provider for ebay, but Spring requires a user-info-uri and a userNameAttribute. Ebay does not support OpenID and therefore there is no user-info-uri and userNameAttribute. How can I disable OIDC or the requirement of the user-info?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **oidc** scope from oauth2 configuration.

```yaml
 spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          ebay:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            scope: profile,email
```